# Combining 2 data sources in crossfilter

Tags: angular, typescript, crossfilter

I'm having some troubles combining some of my data to use in crossfilter.
Let's start by explaining what i want to do;

I have 2 different database tables:

1. Sensors (sensor_id, EUI, longitude, latitude, location_id)
2. Impacts (impact_id, EUI, GyroX, GyroY, GyroZ, AccelX, AccelY, AccelZ and timestamp)

The Sensors table is holding the information for each sensor.
The impacts table is holding the information for the impacts of each sensor.

Now I want to create interactive graphs where i can filter through all the data. So for example when selecting location_id = 1. I want to see all the graphs change it's data to show all data related to location 1.
(So in this case, i'd like to see the impacts and sensors related to location 1)

So first I wrote a function getSensorDataWithImpacts() in my data service. This allowed me to get an array containing the sensors both with it's impacts.

The object [0] looks like this:

```
[
 EUI: 123,
 location_id: 1,
 latitude: 1.285101,
 longitude: 103.769902,
 impacts: {
    Count: 2,
    Items: [
     0:
      EUI: {S: "123"},
      timestamp: {N: "1512028997"}
      accelX: {N: -10}
      accelY: {N:  20}
      accelZ: {N: -30}
      gyroX: {N: -40}
      gyroY: {N:  50}
      gyroZ: {N:  60}
      impactScore: {N:  2000},
     1:
      EUI: {S: "123"},
      timestamp: {N: "1512028900"}
      accelX: {N: -23}
      accelY: {N:  56}
      accelZ: {N: -12}
      gyroX: {N: -43}
      gyroY: {N:  6}
      gyroZ: {N:  12}
      impactScore: {N:  3000},
   ],
   ScannedCount: 2,
 }
```

After receiving this object, I create a a crossfilter of it.
After this I'm able to create multiple dimensions by doing the following:

```
let locationDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
      return d.location_id;
    });
let locationGroup = locationDim.group();
```

I did the same for EUI:

```
 let sensorsDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
      return d.EUI;
    });
 let sensorsGroup = sensorsDim.group();
```

And for Impacts:

```
 let impactDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
      for(let a = 0; a<d.impacts.Items.length; a++){
        return d3.time.minute(new Date(d.impacts.Items[a].timestamp['N'] * 1000));
      }
    });

    let impactGroup = impactDim.group()
      .reduceSum(function (d) {
        for(let a = 0; a<d.impacts.Count; a++){
          return d.impacts.Items[a].impactScore['N'] / 1000;
        }
      });
```

With these dimensions I am able to successfully filter through all my data. I get to see the different locations, different EUI numbers and I get to see 1 impact of each sensor. This is not as expected. I would like to receive all impacts from each sensor.

[Different graphs with 1 impact for each sensor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uERnA.png)

I don't know what i'm doing wrong
Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest flattening your data. It will make this a lot easier. That is, just have a table of impacts, and on each row, also record the sensor information. It's duplicative, and if that becomes a problem there are good ways of dealing with that, but this approach should be a better way to get started.

Comment: Thank you Ethan. I flattened my data more and was able to get things working the way i want them to work.